# Smoothie - water as base liquid, originally?

Tags: language, smoothie

I am wondering, for termbase purposes, about the base liquid for smoothies: is it originally water?

I would appreciate your help as native English speakers, as we were considering equivalents in our language made using milk, yogurt, fruit juice as a base liquid for this drink.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Termbase? What is that?

Comment: @Catija The OP is creating a food taxonomy. Quite a difficult task, especially if it is multi-language, as it seems.

Answer (score 2):

Generally people don't use water, because they don't want watered-down flavors. Fruit juice, milk, and yogurt all provide some flavor, so people tend to like them more.

But you certainly *can* use water if you want. It'll probably work best if you have some good flavorful fruit, and you might end up wanting to add extra sweetness, but it's possible. (I personally don't mind using ice, to get it extra cold with more icy texture, but that's not universal.)

In any case, it's not a strictly defined term; if you have a frozen drink that tastes like it's made out of actual blended fruit (and dairy and whatever else), I'm sure people will call it a smoothie.

Comment: Considering that even smoothie shops like Jamba Juice use ice in all (most?) of their smoothies, I don't think it's that unpopular. Though they use special ice.

Comment: @Catija Maybe I should've said "not universal" - I didn't think it was that unpopular either, but then I discovered plenty of skeptics here: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/54662/1672

Comment: @Catija, special ice? What do you mean?

Comment: @LorelC. They use crushed ice pellets not solid ice the way a homemade smoothie would.

Answer (score 0):

No many people not use water because due to water u cannot get extra good results for your base, so people use milk,juices and yugurt etc.